# What's the difference between storing states in store(model) and class in terms of time efficiency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx

I currently started using `MobX` and it completely makes my classes stateless. And it looks good to me, but I'm wondering if there is any downside in storing your states(`observable` states and methods) in store (Somebody call it model store)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant difference in terms of performance. The thought process behind it is usually "Do I need this state in just this component, or does it have to be shared?"

If it is local state, you can put it right on the component class:

```
@observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  @observable value = '';

  render() {
    return (
      <input value={this.value} onChange={e => this.value = e.target.value} />
    );
  }
}
```

If it is shared state, you can put it in an external store and pass it to the component:

```
const MyComponent = observer((props) => (
  <input
    value={props.myStore.value}
    onChange={e => props.myStore.value = e.target.value}
  />
));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no significant difference"? And I would rather store my state in `store` and make my components functional components.

Comment: If there is no difference, I want to store all states in `store` because it looks better (at least for me).

Comment: https://github.com/binary-com/binary-static/pull/4001/files#diff-1a4e6e30438b6c7b6c67f5e2dd5a585eR2

Comment: I mean that whatever performance difference there are between the two approaches, it will be negligible. If you like to keep it all in a store, then you can go with that. I think local component state fits better in the component itself, because it doesn't bloat the global store and it's much easier to create many instances of a purely modular component, but that's just my opinion.